# rust cargo init occur signature verification failed

Tags: rust

i try to use cargo init to init cargo manage system.

but i can't see the $HOME/.cargo dir generate.

and the shell show

```sh
macmatoMacBook-Air:rust kula$ cargo init
warning: signature verification failed for sources.json

macmatoMacBook-Air:rust kula$ cargo sync
error: No sources defined. You may wish to run "cargo init" then "cargo sync".
```

what's up on the cargo manage system?

my os is mac osx 10.7

Comment: I'm not seeing this error on Linux, but I seem to have to run these commands with `sudo`.  Is it failing on MacOS because of a permission issue (even though the error messages are different)?

Comment: not about permission. i try to use "sudo cargo init" to init a cargo repo.  but there is also "warning: signature verification failed for sources.json".  maybe it's a bug on osx 10.7

Comment: nope, i'm getting the same issue on linux. neither of the below answers fixes it.

Comment: Note: `cargo init` has now completely differeny meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely that you don't have gpg installed so it can't verify the signature of cargo-central's source file, and then proceeds to not work at all.

This situation where signature verification fails is supposed to be non-fatal, but there was a bug in cargo that caused it to not complete the 'init' command.

I've checked in a change to cargo that I believe should allow it to continue even when signature verification fails, but FWIW cargo could use some love to make it more useful and reliable.

Comment: hi , i check the gpg.  it looks ok. gpg version is gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.12

Comment: you are right.  i install gpg. and recompile rust.  then it works! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

cargo appears to shell out to GPG and use crappy regexes on the output. Which fails if your locale isn't what it expects. This worked for me:

```
LC_MESSAGES=C cargo init
```